# python script only in subdirectories and not going back to root

Tags: python, os.walk

My python script uses os.walk to loop trough subdirectories. I am running the script from the current working directory, and want that the script only works in the current working directory and its subdirectories. However, the script goes back to the root and works from there to find all the files. 
So, for example, the directory structure is:
folder1
  - sub1
folder2
  - sub2
  - sub3

If I run my script in folder1, I only want the files from folder1 and sub1, but my script also uses the files from folder2 and sub2 and sub3. 
My script is quite large, but hopefully someone can give me a short answer how to change all the os.walk lines to prevent python to go into an other folder.

```
#next step
print('Start merging contig files')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
            df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"])
            df1['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
    else:
        continue

    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f2:
            df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "SCM"])
            df2['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
    else:
        continue

    filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.fna.output_blastplasmiddb.out.count_plasmiddbhit.out')
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f3:
            df3 = pd.read_csv(f3, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "plasmid_genes"])
            df3['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
    else:
        continue

    #merge dataframes
    dfmerge1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')
    df_end = pd.merge(dfmerge1, df3, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')

    #set NaN in columns to 0
    nan_cols = df_end.columns[df_end.isnull().any(axis=0)]
    for col in nan_cols:
        df_end[col] = df_end[col].fillna(0).astype(int)

    #add column with genes/SCM en round to 2 decimals
    df_end['SCM/genes'] = df_end['SCM']/df_end['genes']
    df_end['SCM/genes'] = df_end['SCM/genes'].round(2)

    #add column with genes/plasmid_genes en round to 2 decimals
    df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'] = df_end['plasmid_genes']/df_end['genes']
    df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'] = df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'].round(2)      

    df_end.to_csv(os.path.join(root,'outputgenesdf.csv'))
print('extra columns;done')

#next step
#CURRENT DIRECTORY 
cd = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())

# concatenate csv files
dfList = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cd):
    for fname in files:
        if re.match("outputgenesdf.csv", fname):
            frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, fname))
            dfList.append(frame)    

df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Comment: *If I run my script in folder2, I only want the files from folder1 and sub1* - Did you mean "If I run my script in folder1..."?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal script that accurately represents the problem that you face, without extra information/code?

Comment: yes my apologies, it must be folder1

Comment: My script is much larger than it is now. If i give a minimum script, I do not know how to represent it.

Comment: It's still pretty confusing. The `if` statements are not necessary, but anyway. If I understand correctly you have your script in `folder1` and you want the `os.walk()` to run only in there. However, you have: `cd = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` this means the root folder of where you are (ie. the parent dir of the `folder1` which includes `folder2` too). So, `os.walk(cd)` will walk on both `folder1` and `folder2`.

Comment: if you are in folder1 it should only process itÄs subdirectories. If you are in the top Directory of folder1, folder2 and folder3 then it will process all.

Comment: @Kev he has this `cd = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())` which means the parent directory of where he stands. Guess what will the `os.walk()` do if you give it the `cd` as a parameter. It will simply walk on all the folders of the parent dir.

Comment: Yes Tasos is right, I am a beginner, so I find it very difficult to understand what the script does and how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on:

> [...] and want that the script only works in the current working directory and its subdirectories.[...]

You can try this:

```
def next_file(directory=os.getcwd(), max_depth=0, depth=0):

    if max_depth < 0 or depth <= max_depth:

        for name in os.listdir(directory):
            with_path = os.path.join(directory, name)

            if os.path.isfile(with_path):
                yield with_path
            else:
                for a_file in next_file(directory=with_path, max_depth=max_depth, depth=depth+1):
                    yield a_file
```

and process your files with:

```
for a_file in next_file(max_depth=1):
    print 'processing file: %s' % a_file
    # do your stuff here
```

use `max_depth` to control the number of nested directories that you want to process. `0` to read files in current directory and `-1` to process all directories. (as in `os.walk`).

#### EDIT

I did a small modification to the file-iteration method.

Here is a complete (and untested) version of your script:

```
def next_file(current_dir=os.getcwd(), max_depth=0, depth=0):

    if max_depth < 0 or depth <= max_depth:

        for name in os.listdir(current_dir):
            with_path = os.path.join(current_dir, name)

            if os.path.isfile(with_path):
                yield current_dir, name
            else:
                for directory, name in next_file(current_dir=with_path, max_depth=max_depth, depth=depth+1):
                    yield directory, name


for directory, name in next_file(max_depth=1):
    print 'file: %s' % name

print('Start merging contig files')

## for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
for directory, name in next_file(max_depth=1):

    ## filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv')
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)

    ## if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    if name == 'genes.faa.genespercontig.csv':
        ## with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
        with open(filepath, 'r')
            df1 = pd.read_csv(f1, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "genes"])
            ## df1['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
            df1['genome'] = filepath
    ## else:  # Not necessary
    ##     continue

    ## filepath = os.path.join(root, 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt')
    ## if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    if name == 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt':
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f2:
            df2 = pd.read_csv(f2, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "SCM"])
            ## df2['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
            df2['genome'] = filepath
    ## else:
    ##     continue

    ## filepath = os.path.join(root, 'genes.fna.output_blastplasmiddb.out.count_plasmiddbhit.out')
    ## if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    if name == 'genes.fna.output_blastplasmiddb.out.count_plasmiddbhit.out':
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f3:
            df3 = pd.read_csv(f3, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names = ["contig", "plasmid_genes"])
            ## df3['genome'] = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(filepath))
            df3['genome'] = filepath
        ## else:
        ##     continue

#merge dataframes
dfmerge1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')
df_end = pd.merge(dfmerge1, df3, on=['genome', 'contig'], how='outer')

#set NaN in columns to 0
nan_cols = df_end.columns[df_end.isnull().any(axis=0)]
for col in nan_cols:
    df_end[col] = df_end[col].fillna(0).astype(int)

#add column with genes/SCM en round to 2 decimals
df_end['SCM/genes'] = df_end['SCM']/df_end['genes']
df_end['SCM/genes'] = df_end['SCM/genes'].round(2)

#add column with genes/plasmid_genes en round to 2 decimals
df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'] = df_end['plasmid_genes']/df_end['genes']
df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'] = df_end['plasmid_genes/genes'].round(2)      

#CURRENT DIRECTORY 
cd = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
df_end.to_csv(os.path.join(cd,'outputgenesdf.csv'))
print('extra columns;done')

#next step
# concatenate csv files
dfList = []

## I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this:
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cd):
    for fname in files:
        if re.match("outputgenesdf.csv", fname):
            frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, fname))
            dfList.append(frame)    

df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Please note that your file processing logic is untested (I tested the file-iteration method). And I'm not familiar with pandas, but in each dataframe you are setting a *gnome* property `df1['genome']` that holds the path of the file. I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Finally, I don't understand your last step where you merge the `outputgenesdf.csv` files into a single data frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can I add this directly to the script, so I do not have to change the script, only add this?

Comment: huum, no. Let me add more detail to my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will test it in the script. With the last step, I am looping over all the subdirs, get the outputgenesdf.csv and concatenate all these files to one large dataframe.

Comment: I tried the script, but it gives an error at the line: df_end.to_csv(os.path.join(root,'outputgenesdf.csv')). I have to change this one as well now, but if I add filepath to this line instead of os.path.join(root), I get: "delimiter must be an 1-character string"

Comment: ah yes. `root` does not exist. I've updated my answer.